# Regex java to find $foo in a text?

Tags: java, regex

How can I define a pattern in java to identify

```
$foo
```

as a word in a text?

Below an example to better explain.
I need to obtain the following result:

```
if word == $foo
then

$FOO yyyy -> found
$foo yyyy -> found
aaa aaaa $foo -> found
yyyy $fooxxx -> not found
yyyy $foo!!! -> Found
$fooaaaa -> not found
$foo: aaa -> found
A.foo -> not found
A .foo -> not found
A?foo -> not found
A foo -> not found
```

I tried this code but it does not work:

```
Pattern word_pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\$"+word+"\\b");
if(word_pattern.matcher(text).find()){
        System.out.println("FOUND!");
        return true;
}else{
    System.out.println(":(");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why is it found for `aaa aaaa $foo` but not `aaa $foo`?

Comment: Sorry it is a mistake, I corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely clear about your requirement, but this will probably work for you:

```
Pattern word_pattern = Pattern.compile("\\B\\$" + word + "\\b", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

`\B` tests for non-word boundary. Since `$` is after `\B`, there must be no character before `$` (beginning of a line) or the character before `$` must be a non-word character for it to match.

You **must** validate that `word` only contains valid characters, which I assume it to be `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, which is the definition of `\w` and. And the exact solution may differ if your definition of valid character is different from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

(I forgot about case-insensitive matching and was reminded by Pshemo's answer)